# Does dplyr's summarize output ever have a deterministic output order?

Tags: r, dplyr

When performing a grouped summary in dplyr, one would normally summarize all target variables in a single command:

```
# Method 1: summarize all target variables in one command
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarize(mpg = mean(mpg),
            disp = mean(disp))
```

However, one might prefer to perform the summarizations separately for greater flexibility & programmability (yes I am aware of `across`, but my impression is that its flexibility is limited). In this case, I assume that one must join the tables together at the end:

```
# Method 2: summarize separately and join
a <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarize(mpg = mean(mpg))

b <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarize(disp = mean(disp))
  
inner_join(a, b, by = 'am')
```

The join could be avoided by just appending the summary from `b` to `a`:

`a$c <- b$disp`

However, *this would assume that the rows of `a` and `b` are in the same order.* This is certainly not assured in general, as typical SQL databases do not guarantee output order. When dplyr uses such a database as a backend, it will presumably reflect whatever random order the database returned the data in.

My question is, does vanilla dplyr (i.e. no external backend) guarantee a certain ordering of rows, such that the non-join solution can be considered safe & robust? I suspect dplyr is not interested in guaranteeing row order, but have not been able to find a definitive statement one way or the other.

Comment: I also have not found any mentions about the determinism of `dplyr` functions. If so it is better to `order` samples explicitly.